What have I built exactly?
I was fooling around with cmos inverters and then I saw what was happening when I tried to increase the gate voltage past Vdd/2 so I tried to take advantage of it and connected it upto a darlington pair bjt emitter follower biased by a 10mA current source made by nmoses.
Its now generating a square wave, but I wanna know how , like I want the circuit analysis. I'll have the screenshot to it here:

Vth for the MOS is ~2.4/2.5V and info on W/L ratio is unknown, If you want to check it out you can simulate the circuit in P R O T O mobile app.
I'm only a 2nd year undergrad so take it easy on me.

Seems like your input sine wave is getting gained up by the inverter to produce a square wave. Not sure what more analysis you need.

Like small signal model  or smth, because When I try this same ckt with other higher values of Vdd, the square wave starts to look like a square wave with a semi circle on high part sorta like- _) ... So like whys that?

You dare not go too high with Vdd - current drawn from Vdd increases dramatically (and would over-heat those MOSfets).

Yeah , you're right, tho I'm just in simulation, not building any actual circuits, tho I'm still curious as to why the output waveform distorts with high Vdd values
